# How to add download feature in MDB datatable React js

Tags: reactjs, datatables, mdbootstrap

I am using MDB Datatable in ReactJs.

This is my ReactComponent.js

```
 render(){
        let reports = this.props.reports.data;
        console.log("reports",reports)

        const data = {
                    columns: [
                      {
                        label: 'ID',
                        field: 'id',
                        sort: 'asc',
                        fixedColumns: true,
                        width: 50
                      },
                      {
                        label: 'Item Title',
                        field: 'title',
                        sort: 'asc',
                        fixedColumns: true,
                        width: 200
                      }
                    ],
                    rows: reports
                  };


        return(
            <Container>
                <MDBDataTable
                      striped
                      bordered
                      hover
                      scrollX
                      data={data}
                    />
            </Container>

        )
    }
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wquq.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnSJn.png)

Table is showing and everything is working fine.

1. Want to remove label "Search" and "Showing 1 to 10 of 49 entries".
2. Want to add a download button to download all data in excel

How can I achieve these?

Answer (score 0):

1. To remove label "Search"

If you use latest version/paid version, the "search" text will disappear by default.

For example: [mdbootstrap exaple](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/react/bartek-malanowski/1104360#js-tab-view)

> Alternative way is using CSS, but you need to fix the responsive
> issue:

```
#dtBasicExample_filter label {
  position: relative;
} 

#dtBasicExample_filter input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

2. remove text "Showing 1 to 10 of 49 entries"

> CSS solution:

```
.dataTables_info {
    display: none;
}
```

3. Since the mdbootstrap not support export excel file currently, you may consider using other library or import other export excel file tool, such as [datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excel) and [KendoReact](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/excel-export/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=npm&utm_campaign=kendo-ui-react-trial-npm-grid)

> I personally use KendoReact on my project, below code is base on your
> code with KendoReact:

```
_export; 

export = () => { 
    this._export.save();
}

render(){
    let reports = this.props.reports.data;
    console.log("reports",reports)

const data = {
            columns: [
              {
                label: 'ID',
                field: 'id',
                sort: 'asc',
                fixedColumns: true,
                width: 50
              },
              {
                label: 'Item Title',
                field: 'title',
                sort: 'asc',
                fixedColumns: true,
                width: 200
              }
            ],
            rows: reports
          };


return(
    <Container>
        <MDBDataTable
              striped
              bordered
              hover
              scrollX
              data={data}
            />
    </Container>

    <ExcelExport 
    data={reports} 
    ref={exporter => this._export = exporter} 
    > 
        <button 
            title="Export Excel" 
            className="k-button k-primary" 
            onClick={this.export} 
        > 
        Export to Excel 
        </button> 
        <Grid style={{ display: 'none' }}> 
           <GridColumn field="id" title="ID" /> 
           <GridColumn field="title" title="Item Title" /> 
        </Grid> 
    </ExcelExport> 
    )
}
```

Before implement it to your code, you may try KendoReact [here](https://stackblitz.com/run/?file=app%2Fmain.jsx) first.